# How can number of subdirectories and files be determined from ls -ld command?

Tags: files, directory, ls

How can number of subdirectories and files be determined from the output of using ls -ld command?

I realize that this command only lists the directories.

Comment: Please provide a simple example of the input and output you're looking for.  Do you want a count of only subdirectories and files at depth 1, or do you want to traverse the entire directory tree?  Is it important that the solution use `ls -ld` for some reason?

Comment: Please add some more details please.

Comment: You can determine the number of subdirectories one level down from the second column of output (number of hard links): you take that number and subtract 2 to get the number of subdirectories.

Comment: Yes it is important that the command is ls -ld. Apparently you can find the number of sub directories and files just from the output of using this command in a directory but I do not see how it is possible.

Comment: `ls -ld` isn't restricted to directories (this isn't what `-d` means). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know how number of subdirectories and number of files can be determined from the output of using ls -ld

Comment: You cannot learn **anything** about subdirectories from the output of `ls -d`. The `-d` option means "list only the arguments of ls; i.e., even if it is a directory, _do not_ list its contents". To see all levels of subdirectories, you need `-R`.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many different possibilities...

If you want to count your files,

```
 ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l
```

same thing for directories,

```
 ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l
```

The sum of the two

```
 ls -l | wc -l
```

All subdirectories within a tree starting with current directory:

```
find . -type d -print | wc -l
```

same thing for all files

```
find . -type f -print | wc -l
```

or perhaps for links

```
find . -type l -print | wc -l
```

The rest by induction